# Meaning of Parent theme in Android

Tags: android, android-theme

Working* with themes in Android has always been difficult for me. I know what themes and styles are in Android, but somehow using them, I feel a little painful.

e.g. one of the cases where I find it hard is the differentiate between parent themes and how to use them accordingly. e.g. difference between ***"Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar"*** and **"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"** where the NoActionBar part remains same but everything other changes.

I have tried over dozens of resources over internet but this above particular topic is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

What I am using in my recent projects is `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar`
what it defines is that the parent theme is a Material 3 Light theme which has no Action Bar, it follows Material3 guidelines and principles,

in the same way, if we have `Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar` then it says it is a theme that is also from the [Material3](https://m3.material.io/) library, follows Material3 guidelines, and has DayNight mode which allows us to follow device theme i.e dark and light themes,

we also used to have `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` it follows Material guidelines from M2 you can check that out [here](https://m2.material.io/)

in the same way, if we use Appcompat themes like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` it says you are using a theme under app compat library which has no action bar,

similarly `Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar` follows design principles given by Google long back and it's too old I have been developing apps for the past 5 years and I saw some devs using this but it's very rare.

it might be a little confusing with all these options but it is very simple there are three main variants we use i.e

`Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar` - Light Theme without an Action Bar
`Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar` - Dark Theme without Action Bar
`Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar` - Day Night theme is used when you want to add both light and dark themes in your app

coming to Material3, Material Components, App Compat, and Material design, it depends on the developer and their team to decide which they are to use but I suggest using Material3 it is subtle, supports dynamic theming, has support from Google and has documentation which makes life easier all the components are explained very well check https://m3.material.io/ for more details

Comment: Is there any guide you've got saying how to use those "parents" efficiently ?

Comment: there is no guide of sorts but it depends on how you want your design to be Material 3 the latest one follows android 12 Material you design principles, while m2 has vibrant colors m3 is very suttle so choose what your app ui fits well also you can customise any theme with any parent as you like

Comment: check out https://m3.material.io/ and https://m2.material.io/ you can find differences

Comment: Can you also include some notes regarding toolbar and themes in answer ? It would be really helpful !

Comment: Toolbar in the sense Themes with toolbar? or just basic toolbar which we use inside appBar

Comment: Themes with toolbar.